# Extremum of $\frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{(1+x^2+y^2)}}$

Tags: maxima-minima

> Find the extremum of
>   $$\frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}$$
>   where $a^2+b^2+c^2>0$.

I managed to find critical point - ($\frac{a}{c}$,$\frac{b}{c}$) if $c \neq0$, and no points otherwise. Value of function at this point looks great: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ if $c>0$, and $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ otherwise. I suppose it's maximum and minimum, but checking it by calculating determinants looks like suicide. Is there easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by the well know [Cauchy inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy's_Inequality) for a proof.

Since by Cauchy's inequality we have
$$
(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+1)\geqslant (ax+by+c)^2.
$$